# how to gracefully stop python sounddevice from within callback

Tags: python, audio, python-sounddevice

I'm using [Python sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/) and [PySoundFile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.1/) to play audio "the hard way", that is, using a non-blocking callback.  (Tip of the hat to https://stackoverflow.com/users/500098/matthias and crew -- these packages are easy to use and do everything I need.)  Note: using sd.play() is much easier, but I've chosen this patk because in my final version I want to do additional processing within the callback method.

I can detect when I've reached the end of the soundfile, but it's not clear how to tell the sounddevice to stop after it plays the last queued buffer.

Here's an example of a callback that DOESN'T work: it plays the entire soundfile, but doesn't stop after processing the last buffer.  In the callback, I raise `sd.CallbackStop()`, but the stream status never becomes `stopped`:

```
    def callback(outdata, frame_count, time, status):
        view = sf.read(frame_count, dtype='float32', out=outdata)
        if (view.size != outdata.size):   # this was the last buffer.
            print('stopping')
            sd.CallbackStop()  

    with sd.OutpuStream(samplerate=sf.samplerate,
                        channels=sf.channels,
                        dtype=np.float32,
                        callback=callback) as ss:
        while (ss.active):
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: You should probably add that there is a *much* easier way to do that using [sd.play()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.play).

Comment: Done.  I made it clear that I want to be able to touch they bits as they go by.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!  Exceptions don't work very well if you don't `raise` them!!  The proper code for the callback is:

```
def callback(outdata, frame_count, time, status):
    view = sf.read(frame_count, dtype='float32', out=outdata)
    if (view.size != outdata.size):   # this was the last buffer.
        # zero the part of outdata not written into  by sf.read()
        outdata[view.shape[0]:,:].fill(0.0)
        print('stopping')
        raise sd.CallbackStop()
```

... and it works just perfectly, playing all the way to the end and stopping after the last buffer has been played.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works, but your example code doesn't look like it *could* work at all! I think instead of `sf.read()` you meant `mysoundfile.read()`, right? Also note that you should *always* fill `outdata` with meaningful values, but in your last block you only fill it partly.

Comment: Not shown in my code: `import soundfile as SoundFile` and `with SoundFile(filename) as sf:`, so `sf.read()` is actually correct.  And good catch: the un-written part of the outdata should be zero filled in the final call.  I'll test and edit the example accordingly.

Comment: @Matthias: do you agree with the fix?

Comment: Yes, now it's looking good! You could still replace `view.shape[0]` with `len(view)` and you could also replace the `size` stuff with `len()`, but I guess that's a matter of taste. I misunderstood the `sf` because typically I use `import soundfile as sf`. And you should be aware if at some point reading the sound file (from hard disk) is slowed down for some reason, this may cause a glitch in playback. That's why `sf.play()` insists on having the whole array in memory before beginning playback.

Comment: Correction: I of course meant `sd.play()` instead of `sf.play()`!

Comment: @fearless_fool would you mind updating your code snippet to include all of the code (with the `import` and the `with SoundFile...`)? I realize this was 3 years ago, but in case you still have it :-) Thanks